# How to select a random subset of a numeric vector to have a specific variance?

Tags: r, sample, variance

I have a vector of numbers of length 10000. The total variance is 0.90. I'd like to choose a random subset of this vector, which can be of any length but should have variance 0.85. Of course, I can do this by sorting the vector in ascending order and gradually removing the elements from either end of the distribution until I get the desired variance. But that'll not be a random selection. I'd like to select individuals randomly.

Update: As G5W pointed out, selecting a subset to have a specific variance is not random. I'd like to know if there is a non-random sampling method to choose a subset with a specific variance.

Comment: If you are choosing a subset to get a specific variance, it is not a random subset.

Comment: So, the only way to reduce the variance is to remove the tails manually?

Comment: Not necessarily remove the tails, There could be other non-random sampling that would achieve a specific variance.

Comment: For some data sets with variance 0.90 it will be simply impossible to choose a subset with variance 0.85, though you can always choose a subset with variance <= 0.85. My guess is that it is an NP-complete problem to determine if there is a subset with a specified variance, so likely NP-hard to find a subset whose variance is as close to the target variance as possible.

Comment: Your mention of *"non-random sampling method"* to me sounds like a heuristic that should be guided by context. Besides a targeted variance (with tolerance), what other attributes are important for this vector of numbers? What is the desired length of the subset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use an iterative method to achieve this in a (sort of) random way.

Let's take a starting vector with 10000 elements and a variance of exactly 0.9:

```r
set.seed(123)
vec <- rnorm(10000, 0, sqrt(0.9024591))
var(vec)
#> [1] 0.9
```

Now, if we want to randomly subset the vector so it has a variance of 0.85, we can select a value at random, and check whether the variance falls when we remove it. If not, we keep it in our vector and sample again. If the variance drops, we remove the item from the vector. We keep repeating this until the variance drops to 0.85:

```
v <- vec

while(var(v) > 0.85)
{
  var_v <- var(v)
  i <- sample(length(v), 1)
  if(var(v[-i] < var_v)) v <- v[-1]
}

var(v)
#> [1] 0.8476715

length(v)
#> [1] 343
```

We could get this closer to 0.85 by backing up once the variance falls below the threshold, and removing whichever single value takes the variance closest to 0.85. It comes down to whether randomness or closeness to 0.85 is your priority

<sup>Created on 2020-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This sometimes falls into a neverending loop (try seed 68). Maybe an escape hatch is needed. While loops based on random sampling to exit are a bit risky.

Comment: @Edward that's true. There is no guarantee that there even _is_ a solution for any given input. If this is anything other than a one-off, you would need something like an iteration counter than increments on every failure of the loop to reduce the variance, resets to 0 when it _does_ reduce the variance and triggers a `break` when it reaches a threshold (a bit like `n_iter` in `nls`). It's also horribly inefficient and statistically dubious, which is my excuse for not implementing such niceties - just showing a quick and dirty way to get a solution (if one exists). Thanks for pointing that out